# Solving 4th order ODE numerically with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to solve this equation analytical, where C and L is constants:
[image]
There is no problem with the general solution, but with the conditions, the expression is close to unsolveable.

[image]

Now I'm trying to solve the problem with Matlab, where I believe i shall use the ode45 solver. I just don't know what to do with the integral and omega which is the value I'm trying to find.

I know that i haven't given any code snippet, but I just can't figure out how to solve this problem in Matlab.

I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried doing?

Comment: I changed the expression and got other conditions, which made it possible to find the particular solution and afterwards solve it iteratively for omega.

Comment: This looks like a [boundary value problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem). `ode45` is designed for [initial value problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem). You should look into, read the documentation, and try the examples for Matlab's [boundary value problem solvers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/boundary-value-problems.html).